# Why is my query crashing?

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I've written the following DB query.
However, the app crashes when I access the list activity that displays the results.

I've traced the error to the method below (other simpler query methods work just fine):

```
public Cursor fetchInterface_HSE_Entries(String string) throws SQLException{
    String[] columns = new String[] {KEY_ROW_ID_INTERFACE, KEY_TEXTVIEW_VALUE, KEY_CATEGORY_OPTIONS, KEY_WORKSCREEN};
    String whereClause = KEY_WORKSCREEN+"=" + string;
    Cursor cursor = db.query(TEXTVIEWS_TABLE, columns, whereClause, null, null, null, null);

    if(cursor != null){
        cursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    return cursor;
}
```

And this is part of my error log:

```
12-31 16:13:38.851: E/AndroidRuntime(480): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: testInterface1: , while compiling: SELECT _id, textviewvalue, categoryoptions, workscreen FROM interfacetable WHERE workscreen=testInterface1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with:

```
String whereClause = KEY_WORKSCREEN+"='" + string + "'";
```

You need to quote text values in your queries, otherwise they will be interpreted as column names (or functions, or whatever).

Note that this is not safe against SQL Injection attacks, you should be using bind variables.

```
String whereClause = KEY_WORKSCREEN+" = ?";
Cursor cursor = db.query(TEXTVIEWS_TABLE, columns, whereClause, 
                         new String[]{string}, null, null, null);
```

Comment: Thanks for warning me about my security issues. I'll look into them. I'm quite the noob with Android and especially with databases, but doing my best to learn

Comment: Humm... someone downvoted this, not sure why. Maybe there's a typo or I'm missing something? Eugen, if you try either of those, could please report if either worked or not so I can correct (or remove) this answer?

Comment: Yep, your code works very well. Thanks a lot for the input, again.

Answer (score 1):

Because you do not put quotes around your whereClause.
Try:

```
String whereClause = KEY_WORKSCREEN+"='" + string + "'";
```

You can clearly see it in your error log:

```
SELECT _id, textviewvalue, categoryoptions, workscreen FROM interfacetable WHERE workscreen=testInterface1
```

should be:

```
SELECT _id, textviewvalue, categoryoptions, workscreen FROM interfacetable WHERE workscreen='testInterface1'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT _id, textviewvalue, categoryoptions, workscreen FROM interfacetable WHERE workscreen=testInterface1
```

As error says you don't have testInterface1 collumn in interfacetable table, i think you should have value instead of testInterface1 in your sql statement. Run your query in db, and you will see the same error.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put your string value in the where clause into quotes.

Answer (score 1):

Workscren is string edit your query and add single quotes. Key-workscreen+"="'+ string +'" like that